# Matplotlib pyplot: XY plots using data in a matrix

Tags: matplotlib

I have a matrix with even numbered columns as X data and the following columns as corresponding Y data. If my matrix is 30x6, I want to see three plots in the figure: c0 vs c1, c2 vs c3, c4 vs c5. Is there a way to plot all data at once without using a for loop? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a `(30x6)` matrix like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(30,6),axis=0)
```

Using a for-loop, this can be plotted in 2 code lines as

```
for i in range(m.shape[1])[::2]:
    plt.plot(m[:,i],m[:,i+1], color="k" )

plt.show()
```

Under the condition that you wish to not use a *for-loop*, this becomes more complicated. I will interprete this condition as no for-loop should appear in the actual code (independent of whether that makes sense or not).
Adding a row of `nan`s and reshaping the matrix would allow for a single `plot` command.

```
m = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(30,6),axis=0)

m2 = np.concatenate((m,np.zeros(m.shape[1])[np.newaxis,:]*np.nan), axis=0)
plt.plot(m2[:,::2].T.flatten(),m2[:,1::2].T.flatten(), color="k" )  

plt.plot()
```